# A strange account appear at login to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: users

An account name **student account** appear at login , what is thes account and how to disable it .

Hint i disable guest at `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

How to disable this account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the last Ubuntu where service accounts that are disabled for login, show up in the login screen. For instance, in mine the user Postgres appears since I installed postgresql service (database system).

Check if the user really exist by listing the home directory:

```
ls /home/
```

If there's not something like /home/student maybe the user is one of those service accounts. You can check them with users-admin:

```
sudo apt-get install users-admin
users-admin
```

May I add, in my case, this phantom user also shows up under the users menu on the top left of the Unity panel.